# How to use a Content Provider with Objectify/Cloud Endpoints (App Engine)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-contentprovider, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am designing an **Android Client** for an **App Engine** application that utilizes Google's NoSQL **Datastore**, along with **Objectify** and **Cloud endpoints**.

Server side, I have a `User` and a `UserEndpoint`, which can be reused locally. This Android application should work offline - so I plan on using a **Content Provider to store offline data**.

Reusing these classes locally that I created server side is pretty cool, but this would only seem to work as long as I have internet access. How can I c*onnect these reusable server-side classes with a content provider* so my client app functions offline?

Are there any guides out there for syncing a local SQLite db to an App Engine NoSQL Datastore accessed via Objectify/CloudEndpoints?

Answer (score 0):

For the application to work in offline you need to store the data in SQLLite as you are doing. To sync the data with your datastore, you can use  SyndAdapter (http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) and Cloud Endpoint to expose your datastore objects. To notify the client from the changes on the server you can use Google Cloud messaging (https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

I am afraid, there is no out of the box solution for you as of yet.

Comment: I figured as such. What would you recommend? My best guess is to just extend the server side classes when they're reused locally to enable content provider syncing?